# Need help understanding Ruby dynamics programming

Tags: ruby

I need help understanding `arr.partition(&a.method('>'))` is doing. I know its dynamic and we are passing a method as a block to array.partition method. Also how would I achieve the same without using meta programming

```
a=13
arr=[10,11,13,22]
left,right= arr.partition(&a.method('>'))
p left
p right
```

Output

```
[10, 11]
[13, 22]
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with meta programming, it’s plain old good ruby.

```
left, right = arr.partition(&a.method('>'))
```

What is really happening here, is:

- get an instance of [`Method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html) class, namely [`Integer#>`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-3E) (by calling [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method) on `13`)
- convert it to proc by calling [`Method#to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-to_proc) (due to `&`)
- pass this proc as a block to [`Array#partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition).

Step by step:

```
> 13.method(:>)
#⇒ Integer#>(arg1)
> p = 13.method(:>).to_proc
#⇒ #<Proc:0x005652125f8b50 (lambda)>
> [10, 11, 13, 22].partition &p
#⇒ [[10, 11], [12, 13]]
```

The same might be achieved with:

```
a = 13
arr = [10, 11, 13, 22]
left, right = arr.partition { |element| a > element }
#⇒ [[10, 11], [12, 13]]
```

Comment: I am getting explanation from your answer which I was thinking yesterday from one of your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Now this line is confusing `convert it to proc by calling Method#to_proc (due to &)` It's not converting to due to &, eh? It's converting while you are calling `to_proc` ?

Comment: @Rajagopalan actually both; I have added `to_proc` to `p = 13.method(:>).to_proc` for clarity (maybe I should not,) and `&` indeed converts the argument to `proc`, but since `Proc#to_proc` returns `self`, everything works as expected.